# codeigniter session loading error: No such file or directory

Tags: codeigniter

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/):

however when I access to

http://localhost/index.php/user_authentication/

I got this get warning and cannot get the code running:

```
Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
```

When I remove the `$this->load->library('session');`

the warnings are gone so I am pretty sure I got the error in loading the session library.

I have read that the issue is fixed by changing $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();

but i still get the warning.

I even tried adding this code to my controller:
mkdir("/thisisthedirectory", 0700);

then changed my $config['sess_save_path'] = "/thisisthedirectory"; but it doesn't work

nor $config['sess_save_path'] = "C:\thisisthedirectory";

Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set your session save path something like

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/';
```

> Folder Permissions 0700

Config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Note: Make sure you have followed the Codeigniter Style Guide For [File Naming](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming) and [Class Naming](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I already issued mkdir("/thisisthedirectory", 0700); then changed $config['sess_save_path'] = "/thisisthedirectory"; however i still get the warning and code wont run successfully. I also tried using $config['sess_save_path'] = "C:\thisisthedirectory"; but it wont work also

Answer (score 0):

While you are working with .env file and your **sessionSavePath** will not absolute it will show error like this

set your sessionSavePath as absolute path as below

```
app.sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler'
app.sessionCookieName = 'ci_session'
app.sessionSavePath = '/home/user/public_html/project/public/NULL'
app.sessionMatchIP = false
app.sessionTimeToUpdate = 300
app.sessionRegenerateDestroy = false
```

It will fix your problem

Thank you

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Answer (score 0):

you may try to load parent constructor like this

```
parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('session');
```

I hope it solves the problem